# Split XML using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax

I have following xml file.

```
<Engineers>
    <Engineer>
        <Name>JOHN</Name>
        <Position>STL</Position>
        <Team>SS</Team>
    </Engineer>
    <Engineer>
        <Name>UDAY</Name>
        <Position>TL</Position>
        <Team>SG</Team>
    </Engineer>
    <Engineer>
        <Name>INDRA</Name>
        <Position>Director</Position>
        <Team>PP</Team>
    </Engineer>
</Engineers>
```

I need to split this xml into smaller xml strings when Xpath is given as Engineers/Enginner.

Smaller xml strings are as follows

```
<Engineers>
    <Engineer>
        <Name>INDRA</Name>
        <Position>Director</Position>
        <Team>PP</Team>
    </Engineer>
</Engineers>

<Engineers>
    <Engineer>
        <Name>JOHN</Name>
        <Position>STL</Position>
        <Team>SS</Team>
    </Engineer>
</Engineers>
```

I have implemented following so far using SAX which we can get the elements inside XML but not as what I want.How can I proceed??

```
public class ReadSAX
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {

              SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
              SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

              DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

   public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes attributes)
                    throws SAXException {

                  System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);



                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName)
                        throws SAXException {

                      System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                    throws SAXException {

                  System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));


                 }

              };

              File file = new File("c:\\file.xml");
              InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
              Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");

              InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
              is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

              saxParser.parse(is, handler);


            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use such a low-level coding approach?

In XSLT 2.0 it's simply

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="Engineers/Engineer">
    <xsl:result-document select="{position()}.xml">
      <Engineers>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </Engineers>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

and if that takes too much memory, get a streaming XSLT 3.0 processor which will solve the problem.

Comment: @Micheal Kay hi sir..how can i use this with a java class to get the result?

Comment: Have you tried google "Run XSLT transformation from Java"? But rather than google, if you're doing XML programming from Java you really should be using Elliotte Rusty Harold's book: http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/

Comment: @Micheal Kay Thank you very much sir.This helped a lot.

Comment: @Micheal Kay Sir..If you can provide me some details about getting streaming XSLT 3.0 proceesor thing.Since I am new to XSLT it would be a great help to understand the whole concept.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really a StackOverflow question, let alone a comment. Google is your friend. Try watching the video of Abel Braaksma's conference talk here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeSQ4ompB1g

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to use VTD-XML's cut and paste ability... this paper, **entitled performance analysis of java apis for xml** processing, will tell you more on vtd-xml..

http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
public class splitXML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException, IOException {
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\input.xml", false)){
            System.out.println("error");
            return;
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/engineers/engineer");
        int i=0,n=0;
        FileOutputStream fos =null;
        byte[] stag="<engineers>".getBytes();
        byte[] etag="</engineers>".getBytes();
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            fos.write(stag);
            fos = new FileOutputStream("d:\\xml\\output"+(++n)+".xml");
            long l = vn.getElementFragment();
            fos.write(vn.getXML().getBytes(), (int)l, (int)(l>>32));
            fos.write(etag);
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```